# Are Cont's "stylized facts" based on reliable evidence?

Tags: volatility, stylized-facts

A highly cited article ["Empirical properties of asset returns: stylized facts and statistical issues"](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/713665670) by R. Cont use the **Figure 8.** below to illustrate

> the well-known phenomenon of volatility clustering: large price variations are more likely to be followed by large price variations.

[image]

Note the burst of autocorrelation of $x^2$ (red dotted line) at lag $\approx 85$.

Later on the author publishes even higher cited book ["Financial Modelling with Jump Processes"](https://www.crcpress.com/Financial-Modelling-with-Jump-Processes/Tankov-Cont/p/book/9781584884132) (together with P. Tankov). On the **FIGURE 7.3** in the book (shown below) the same autocorrelation of $x^2$ as above is shown. But this time  *without* the burst!

[image]

Also I have to admit that I couldn't understand x axis legend for both pictures above.

So it would be great if someone who has access to S&P 500 Index futures intraday 1-minute data for 1991-1995 could calculate autocorrelation function of squared price increments and publish it here!

**UPDATE**
I've quickly prepared a similar graph using data for 1998-2012 kindly provided by @David Addison. In appears that

- autocorellations are two times higher than in the article and in the book
- power law (blue line) does not seem to be a very good fit

[image]

P.S. I do not claim that above I and David has provided a reliable evidence of anything. Rather it should be considered as an additional justification for the question and request. Let's reproduce the results of [Professor Rama Cont](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/people/r.cont) !

Comment: I have index futures data from 1997-2011... not what you're looking for, but may be useful to your broader analysis.

Comment: @DavidAddison Thanks! I could calculate acf for 1997-2011 and add it to the question as an additional illustration

Comment: No problem. Here's a link that I will temporarily put up for you: http://the-world-is.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/ES.zip

Comment: @DavidAddison Are the data in EST timezone?

Comment: I'm actually not certain. My apologies. I downloaded the data a while back from my broker, so it's either Western Or Eastern ST.

Comment: The time scale on Prof. Cont's chart is is the number of 5 minute intervals. So 100 minutes on your chart corresponds to 20 fivemin intervals on his chart.

Comment: S&P futures trading ends at 16:15 Eastern time each day (and always has). So this should tell you what time zone is used in your data. When you do see trading stop for a little while?

Comment: @noob2 Using the same arguments I concluded that the data in EST. For every trading day I kept only minutes between 9:29 and 16:15. Trading actually stops at 16:15 or little earlier.

Comment: @noob2 Please note that Prof. Cont uses data for 1991-1995 while I have only 1998-2012. I'd very much appreciate the data for 1991-1995 so I could reproduce (one of) the graphs of Prof. Cont! I don't think it is possible to reproduce both of them.

Comment: @noob2 Could you please email it to zer0hedge@enricherclub.com ?

Comment: OK, check your email

Comment: @noob2 Thanks! I responded with the draft analysis. Results of Cont are not reproduced. I will finalize and publish here as soon as I'm back from vacation in the beg of Aug.

Answer (score 1):

The 'burst' in the first figure is just due to overnight returns, so nothing fancy (the unit if you read the axis is T/5 min so 84 corresponds to 84 x 5 min= 7 hours = 1 trading day). There is always a peak at 1-day lag due to overnight returns.

Comment: In this case it will be autocorrelation of 5 mins at closing with 5 mins at opening, not overnight?